# How do you create your burn-down charts apart from using paid tools

Tags: scrum, agile, tools, burn-charts

If you're NOT paying for software like Jira, what/how do you create your own burn-down charts?

I have seen a few tools out there for creating burn-down charts.  The one I'm most familiar with is setting up a template in Excel and working that way.  I've also seen third-party add on's for Chrome and Trello.

Comment: You can use anything that works for you, including Excel, Pandoc tables, or AsciiDoc. For a quick sample, see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/212975/57614.

Comment: [Tool Requests are out of scope for PM:SE](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), although the topic continues to be debated.  The core of the question is interesting; I suggest that we refocus the question on techniques that can be implemented in any tool.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool, though you could argue about the free part, for me is a **whiteboard or flip chart and a marker**. Though any sheet of paper and pen will do.

It's **easy to implement**, too. Just put numbers on your cards, draw the two axes and you're set.

Start from there and **get your process on order first**. Once you and your team have established your own flavor of scrum, you will know what
 your requirements are and screening tools will be a quick exercise, but not knowing what the tool is supposed to do, flexibility is key. And not much can beat board and marker in that respect.

*Source:* my own experience building and coaching scrum teams